# Xcode 14.2 Preview Not Working but Simulator Works

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui, mobile

I'm facing the issue when I try to start the preview, it shows me this error:

```
Timed out waiting for connection to dtservicehub after 15.0 seconds
```

My XCode version is 14.2, and my MacOS Version is 12.6.2 Monterey.

Simulator works perfectly, but preview won't.

I tried to change between different devices, including Any iOS Device...

Tried. to uncheck Canvas automatically reload, and everything else that I found on SO.

Comment: It's just on every project, even if I create the new one.